# Flutter: Different sized children (all with same max size) in GridView?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm learning Flutter/Dart, and I'm trying to make a GridView that takes a list of Button Widgets as children.  The buttons should have varying sizes from one to the next. The only thing I could find at all relative to this was for problems making a StaggeredGridView, but to clarify I want a normal grid view, just for the buttons to have different overall sizes with the grid cell being the max size.

I've already tried changing the button type, creating a container within the container with the button as the child of the latter container. Nothing seems to affect the final size of the buttons displayed. I have also tried editing the width and height of the button being built directly as opposed to having the container with the button in it.

```
Widget makeButton(B b){
  return new Container(
    width: 200.0,
    height: 200.0,
    child: Container(
      width: b.getSize(),
      height: b.getSize(),
      child: RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.red[50],
        child: Text(b.getText),
        onPressed: ((){...});
    )
 );
}

List<Widget> genButtons(int lSize){
  List<Widget> _list = new List<Widget>(lSize);
  for (int i = 0; i < lSize; i++){
    //new B(String text, double size) 
    _list[i] = makeButton(new B(i.toString(), (i+1)*50.0));
  }
  return _list;
 }

Widget buildGrid(int crossCount, double padding, double spacing){
    return new GridView.count(
      primary: true,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(padding),
      crossAxisSpacing: spacing,
      crossAxisCount: crossCount,
      children: _myList,
    );
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('HELLO'),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: buildGrid(5, 10.0, 5.0, context),
        color: Colors.amber[100],
      )
  );
}
```

My goal end result is to have the buttons being created in the list have varying sizes within the cells of the gridview. They can all have the same max size, being the size of the cell itself. I would like to avoid implementing a StaggeredGridView, if possible.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: add some image, what exactly you want for,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is in:

```
Widget makeButton(B b){
  return new Container(
    width: 200.0,
    height: 200.0,
    child: Container(
      width: b.getSize(),
      height: b.getSize(),
      child: RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.red[50],
        child: Text(b.getText),
        onPressed: ((){...});
    )
 );
}
```

Since you've made a container with width & height of 200, and then put another container inside it (presumably with a smaller size), but then never told that inner container where to go within its parent, flutter overrides the width & height you specified for the inner button.

I assume what you want is for it to be centered, so wrap the inner Container with a [Center widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html). If center isn't what you want, use an [Align widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html).

The other issue is that I'm not 100% sure a button widget will size itself to its parent. To that end, rather than using a container you might be able to put the RaisedButton in a ButtonTheme where you specify minWidth and height. Another option would be to forego the button completely and use an InkWell instead as that will give you the 'tap' effect without the button-specific behavior of trying to show text within it etc.

Comment: Sorry for late response, I was just able to try your solution using the Center widget and it worked! (I changed the buttons to FloatingActionButton 's as well)